# how do I add onchange="this.form.submit()" to a Flask/WTFoms HTML page

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to make it so that when I change an input filed on the HTML page the form submits automatically. But the page is generated by Flask/WTForms and it won't let me insert onchange="this.form.submit()" as a parameter for when it builds the page.

I'm new to coding and I've tried lots of things - but this problem is really elusive!

Here is the Template HTML File

```
<h5>Give input part 1</h5>
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form id=myform method=post action="">
<table>
    <dl>
        {{ render_field(form.A) }}
        {{ render_field(form.B) }}
    </dl>
</table>
```

and the Helper Macro File (_formhelpers.html)

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
<tr>
<td>{{ field.name }}</td>
<td>{{ field(size=20) }} </td>
<td><font color="blue">{{ field.label }}</font></td>
<td>{{ field.description | safe}}</td>
{% if field.errors %}
  <td><ul class=errors>
  {% for error in field.errors %}
    <li><font color="red">{{ error }}</font></li>
  {% endfor %}</ul></td>
{% endif %}
</tr>
{% endmacro %}
```

and my Model

```
from   wtforms import Form, validators, IntegerField,

class InputForm(Form):
    B = IntegerField(
        label='Integer', default=BB, description="this description",
        validators=[validators.NumberRange(0, 30)])
```

I just want

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

to show up in the rendered HTML page like this!

```
<p><input id="B"  name="B"  type="text" onchange="this.form.submit()"  > <label for="B">Integer</label></p>
```

Comment: That has to be done in the jinja macro `render_field`. Find the code for that macro and modify it so that the fields are rendered with the `onchange` attribute set accordingly.

Comment: Adjust `field(size=20)` to `field(size=20, onchange="this.form.submit()")`.